# Unable to install Aptana Studio 3 on Eclipse jee-2020-03

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, aptana

Trying to install Aptana Studio 3 plugin on Eclipse jee-2020-03 MacOS Big Sur using the following Work With location: http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/plugin/update/rc/

The version:     Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.6.0.201407100643-7f7D37k6bPlkbrRb8WuT8t_CCL4C

After restarting Eclipse I get the following error:

An internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle: /Users/mike_home/eclipse/jee-2020-03/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/2364/0/.cp/bundles/capistrano.ruble".
(LoadError) load error: builtin/java/java.lang -- java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7ccd772b

I am using 16.0.5-jdk to run Eclipse.

Additionally, I tried installing the dmg standalone version 3.7.1 and that also fails with lots of these errors:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2021-08-15 15:43:09.275
!MESSAGE Could not install bundle plugins/org.apache.batik.util_1.8.0.v201702141941.jar   A bundle is already installed with the name "org.apache.batik.util" and version "1.8.0.v20170214-1941

Is there anything I can do to get this working.  My preference is to use the Eclipse Plugin on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I guess consider this solved or at least I've moved on.

I ended up installing another Eclipse and setting the JDK to 1.8 because I found issues relating to Java level.  Then it almost installed but there was another link http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/update/ that was added to the list during install that was not checked so I checked it and the install completed.  However the start page url was wrong and not accessible along with numerous other issues so I decided to go back to vim and other manual methods which always work.  I'd say that the Aptana plug-in is useless for Rails at least as was the standalone app which I was never able to install effectively.